# Custom filename for uploaded Image through admin interface

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a Django model with an `ImageField()` field. Now I'd like to rename the filename of the image (based on a unique CharField of the same model) before it gets saved to the filesystem. Additionally, if an image with the same filename already exists, the existing file should be renamed and the newly uploaded file should keep its filename.

I am not quite sure what's the correct or preferred way to do it. Should I override [ModelAdmin.save_model()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model), do it in the [Model.save()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) method or write an own custom file storage?

Can anyone give me some hits how I can accomplish this? Any tips or sample code are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine two mechanisms here: passing an `upload_to` argument in the field's definition and a custom `FileSystemStorage` backend.

Here is a dummy model with an upload_to callable:

```
def upload_bar(instance, filename):
    # Do something with the filename
    return new_filename

class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_bar)
    ...
```

And a custom dummy FileSystemStorage backend:

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

class OverwriteStorage(FileSystemStorage):
    def _save(self, name, content):
        if self.exists(name):
            # Rename it 
        return super(OverwriteStorage, self)._save(name, content)
    def get_available_name(self, name):
        return name
```

However I would be very cautious in meddling with existing files (ie changing existing files' names). Note that Django does not remove the file from the filesystem even when the object is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution to get unique filenames like `18f6ad9f-5cec-4420-abfd-278bed78ee4a.png`

models.py

```
import os
import uuid
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

def make_upload_path(instance, filename):
    file_root, file_ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    dir_name = '{module}/{model}'.format(module=instance._meta.app_label, model=instance._meta.module_name)
    file_root = unicode(uuid.uuid4())
    name = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, dir_name, file_root + file_ext.lower())

    # Delete existing file to overwrite it later
    if instance.pk:
        while os.path.exists(name):
            os.remove(name)

    return os.path.join(dir_name, file_root + file_ext.lower())

class YourModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to=make_upload_path)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can access self.image.name from Model.save()

http://lightbird.net/dbe/photo.html